# How to define printf in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I am learning Java in Eclipse IDE. I cannot figure out how to get the printf to work or to define it. I have checked and I am using the correct compiler for the Java I have which is 1.6. This is the error I am getting:

```
Syntax error on token ".", ; expected
The method printf(String, int) is undefined for the type Addition
```

The program:

```
// Fig 2.7: Addition.java
// Addition program that displays the sum of two numbers.
import java.util.Scanner; // program uses class Scanner

public class Addition
{
// main method begins execution of Java application
public static void main( String[] args )
{
    // create a Scanner to obtain input from the command window
    Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );

    int number1; // first number to add
    int number2; // second number to add
    int sum; // sum of number1 and number2

    System.out.print( "Enter first integer: "); // prompt
    number1 = input.nextInt(); // read first number from user

    System.out.print( "Enter second integer: "); // prompt
    number2 = input.nextInt(); // read second number from user

    sum = number1 + number2; // add numbers, then store total in sum

    System out.println( "Sum is %d\n", sum ); // display sum        

} // end method main
} // end class Addition
```

I've tried the auto-fix from Eclipse but it will still give me the error on token ".".

Comment: printf is C function as per my knowledge, you need to write `system.out.println("output you want")` to print on console.

Comment: It seems to not like the two items inside the parens, if I only put a string inside it is OK. Println gives the identical error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a `.`:

```
System out.println( "Sum is %d\n", sum ); // display sum
```

Should be:

```
System.out.println( "Sum is %d\n", sum ); // display sum
```

Comment: Since when does `println` take two parameters?

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println("the out put sum is"+ sum).
```

if you want to display the output in the console then this is the method in java using eclipse .

Answer (score 0):

In Java, printf is called [format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29):

```
 System.out.format("Sum is %d\n", sum);
```

Just like everything else, it is not a standalone function, but a method.

If you wanted to implement this yourself, you'd need to read up on varargs.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `System.out.println` like this:

```
System.out.println("Sum is " + sum);
```